# Building update object in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

This Code below seems terrible to me but I am not sure the best practices on building update objects on the frontend.

```
buildTaskUpdateObject() {
    this.tasks.forEach(task => {
        debugger;
        const taskRoutingUpdate = new TaskRoutingUpdate();
        taskRoutingUpdate.taskGuid = task.taskGuid;
        taskRoutingUpdate.printer = this.selectedEquipment.$id;
        this.confirmRoutingUpdate.push(taskRoutingUpdate);
    });
}
```

Are there best practices around taking a collection of objects and extracting certain pieces to update the db with?

Comment: That's not entirely dissimilar to what I do. YoukouleleY makes a good point. Side-note: don't put `debugger` into your actually source code, just use breakpoints in devtools. There is a non-zero risk that you push that into production.

Comment: For some reason my breakpoints don't work, so I have been using debuggers. I agree they are stupid and risk prone for production.

Comment: Ah that's interesting. Perhaps you are missing source maps? Not the main problem but something to look at eventually. I wouldn't call it "stupid" necessarily, just risky. Sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could be simplified like this:

```
class TaskRoutingUpdate {
  constructor(obj?: any) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
}



buildTaskUpdateObject() {
  this.tasks.forEach(({ taskGuid }) => {
    this.confirmRoutingUpdate.push(new TaskRoutingUpdate({ taskGuid, printer: this.selectedEquipment.$id }));
  });   
}
```

Comment: I like the look of this a lot more. I was thinking there might be a rxjs method that could perform this job, but that might be overkill for what i am trying to do here.

Comment: Indeed, you don't need to handle events here